# Unable to mount root file system as read-only at boot

Tags: debian, raspbian, readonly, root-filesystem

I am running Raspbian Buster on a raspberry pi, and I have tried to make the filesystem read-only as I don't need to write data and I want to spare my sdcard.

I have followed a guide that basically:

1. Configures the operating system to write all temporary files to the `tmpfs` file system which resides in memory;
2. Configures additional services to also use the `tmpfs` file system;
3. Redirects all system log files to memory.

Everything seems to work except that at boot the flags in `/etc/fstab` `ro` are ignored, so I have to manually type the command to mount as read-only the root partition (for which i am using an alias):

```
alias ro='sudo mount -o remount,ro / ; sudo mount -o remount,ro /boot'
alias rw='sudo mount -o remount,rw / ; sudo mount -o remount,rw /boot'
```

This is the `/etc/fstab` file:

```
proc            /proc           proc    defaults          0       0
PARTUUID=6c586e13-01  /boot           vfat    defaults,ro          0       2
PARTUUID=6c586e13-02  /               ext4    defaults,noatime,ro  0       1
# a swapfile is not a swap partition, no line here
#   use  dphys-swapfile swap[on|off]  for that
tmpfs /var/log tmpfs nodev,nosuid 0 0
tmpfs /var/tmp tmpfs nodev,nosuid 0 0
tmpfs /tmp tmpfs nodev,nosuid 0 0
```

Comment: Can you provide a link to said guide?

Comment: Sure, here is the link: https://medium.com/swlh/make-your-raspberry-pi-file-system-read-only-raspbian-buster-c558694de79